# Distribution Provisioning Profiles pending

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, profile

I have succesfully finished testing my app on iphone by AdHoc Distrubution and now wanted to submit for AppStore. But there is a problem during creating a Distribution Provisioning Profile for AppStore.

After creating this Profile the status is still **PENDING**. How long it takes? There were no delay after creating Distributing profile for AdHoc testing.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but can't you approve the certificate yourself in the portal?

Comment: It's not a problem with certificate. I have a valid certificate for distribution. Problem is with Provisionig Profile for Distribution by AppStore.

Comment: Something appears to be broken, I'm seeing this too for the first time.  Everytime for the last year it's been virtually instantaneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has never taken more than a minute or two for me, and I have done it a dozen times in the past two years.  I would try logging out and back in, and if that does not work maybe make a new one, and if that fails, tell Apple.

Comment: logging out and back didn't work. It was just kind of a big lag in the Apple system. After 2 hours status has changed to Active.

Comment: Quality paid service.

Answer (score 2):

I too have faced this problem . I have waited upto 25 minutes . This is issue at the Apple Server . Now it is working fine .